# Automorphisms of the injective envelope

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a separable $C^∗$-algebra and $(I(A),\kappa)$ be its injective envelope. WLOG assume that $I(A)$ is a monotone complete $C^*$-algebra, and $\kappa:A\to I(A)$ is the identity map.

Let $\textrm{Aut}(I(A))$ denote the set of all *-automorphisms of $I(A)$. For a subgroup $G\subseteq\textrm{Aut}(I(A))$, let $E_G(A)$ be the $C^∗$-algebra generated by $\{\psi(A): \psi\in G\}$. Simply write $E(A)$ when $G=\textrm{Aut}(I(A))$. Clearly $$\psi(E_G(A))\subseteq E_G(A)\hspace{9mm}\forall\psi\in G$$
and it is the smallest such $A\subseteq E\subseteq I(A)$ with this property.

For the questions, suppose that $I(A)$ is not a von Neumann algebra.

**Question 1:** Is $E(A)=I(A)$?

**Question 2:** What extra property ensures $E_G(A)=I(A)$ for $G$ the set of inner automorphisms?